# Invoking GCloud Function without Authentication

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I am pretty new to using gcloud functions.

I have a google cloud function which is supposed to start up a VM instance, but I want to invoke this function from a website without authentication (for now) when sending the HTTP request. How can I do this?

I also don't need to send any params, just need to invoke function

Here is my code for a simple website to invoke the cloud function, though this seems to be using auth which I don't want to do, I have disabled authentication when making the function in the console:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
    <div class="bordered-text-block">
        <h1>VM Controls</h1>
        <button id="id_start_button" onclick="startVM()">Start
        </button>
        <button id="id_stop_button" onclick="stopVM()">Stop
        </button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function startVM() {
            const fetch = require('node-fetch');

            // TODO(developer): set these values
            const REGION = '<my region>';
            const PROJECT_ID = '<project name>';
            const RECEIVING_FUNCTION = '<function name>';

            // Constants for setting up metadata server request
            // See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature
            const functionURL = `https://${REGION}-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/${RECEIVING_FUNCTION}`;
            const metadataServerURL =
                'http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=';
            const tokenUrl = metadataServerURL + functionURL;

            exports.callingFunction = async (req, res) => {
                // Fetch the token
                const tokenResponse = await fetch(tokenUrl, {
                    headers: {
                        'Metadata-Flavor': 'Google',
                    },
                });
                const token = await tokenResponse.text();

                // Provide the token in the request to the receiving function
                try {
                    const functionResponse = await fetch(functionURL, {
                        headers: { Authorization: `bearer ${token}` },
                    });
                    res.status(200).send(await functionResponse.text());
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.status(500).send('An error occurred! See logs for more details.');
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would this be a solution: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment

Comment: You don't need any of the token|auth or metadata code if your function permits unauthenticated requests. I'm unfamiliar with `fetch` but all you should need to do is the `let resp = await fetch(functionURL); console.log(resp);`. Depending on what your function returns, you may need to parse the `resp` into still useful.

Comment: If you don't need to provide params, you should be able to open the `functionURL` in your browser to confirm that it works. Alternatively, if you have `curl` installed, you can `curl --request GET ${functionURL}`. Replace `${function URL}` with the value (`https://...cloudfunctions.net/...`)

Comment: Hey DazWilkin, thanks for the reply. I was wondering how I can do this similar cURL function in JS. I want to incorporate this into an HTML website. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on my comment, here's the simplest answer that should work.

> **NOTE** I think you must ensure your Cloud Functions returns appropriate CORS headers
>
> - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
> - `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`

I wrote a Cloud Function in Golang:

```golang
package p

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "net/http"
)

type Message struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func WebPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    m := Message{
        Name: "Freddie",
    }
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(m)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), 500)
        return
    }
}
```

I deployed this Function:

```sh
PROJECT="<your-project>"
REGION="<your-region>"
FUNCTION="<your-function>"

gcloud projects create ${PROJECT}

BILLING=$(gcloud beta billing accounts list --format="value(name)")
gcloud beta billing projects link ${PROJECT} --billing-account=${BILLING}

for SERVICE in "cloudbuild" "cloudfunctions"
do
  gcloud services enable ${SERVICE}.googleapis.com \
  --project=${PROJECT}
done

gcloud functions deploy ${FUNCTION} \
--entry-point=WebPage \
--source=. \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--allow-unauthenticated \
--region=${REGION} \
--runtime=go113 \
--trigger-http
```

You can grab your function's endpoint in curl:

```sh
URL=$(\
  gcloud functions describe ${FUNCTION} \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

curl \
--silent \
--include \
--header "Accept: application/json" \
--request GET \
${URL}
```

Yields:

```
HTTP/2 200 
access-control-allow-methods: GET
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/json
...

{"name":"Freddie"}
```

Then you can `GET` the value and put it into an HTML `id`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
<div id="result">/div>

<script>
    const PROJECT = "<your-project>";
    const REGION = "<your-region>";
    const FUNCTION = "<your-function>";

    const ID = "result";

    const URL = `https://${REGION}-${PROJECT}.cloudfunctions.net/${FUNCTION}`;

    fetch(URL,{
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => JSON.stringify(json))
    .then(html => document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = html);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tested this (locally) using Caddy:

```sh
docker run \
--rm \
--name=caddy \
--interactive --tty \
--publish=80:80 \
--volume=$PWD/index.html:/usr/share/caddy/index.html \
--volume=caddy_data:/data \
caddy
```

And then browsing `http://localhost:80`, I get:

```
{"name":"Freddie"}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use AppEngine, the easiest way to configure a cron job is with GCP Scheduler: https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating

Just click through the UI and specify the 5 minute interval and your AppEngine http address and you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing some things up. You are appending two URLs as the tokenUrl, which will probably you an error:

```
const tokenUrl = metadataServerURL + functionURL;
```

First allow all users to authenticate to invoke your function (not recommended to keep it this way), which you probably already did.

```
gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding ${RECEIVING_FUNCTION} \
    --member="allUsers" \
    --role="roles/cloudfunctions.invoker "
```

Then you could test your function with a simple get request, which, depending on the code of your cloud function should give you a 200 status code. Testing can also easily be done from the GCP console. Probably you should also pass something as the request's body since your cloud function needs to know whether to stop or start the instance, but this is not clear from your question.

```
curl -x GET https://${REGION}-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/${RECEIVING_FUNCTION}
```

When you know the cloud function is working correctly, you could rewrite your code to something like:

```
function startVM() {
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    
    const REGION = '<my region>';
    const PROJECT_ID = '<project name>';
    const RECEIVING_FUNCTION = '<function name>';
    const functionURL = 'https://${REGION}-${PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/${RECEIVING_FUNCTION}';
    
    exports.callingFunction = async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const functionResponse = await fetch(functionURL);
            res.status(200).send(await functionResponse.text());
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            res.status(500).send('An error occurred! See logs for more details.');
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am able to get the cURL function to work with the `cURL` command, but the last code does not work. Do I just put this in the <script> section of the HTML file and it will work? It doesn't seem to do it when I tried

Comment: Since the API is working. I would suggest you focus on learning some basic javascript/nodejs, so you know how to debug your frontend.